# Inner shadow to div in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I created an inner shadow for a div as in the following css code:

```
.gil_Help_ContentArea {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0px; 
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #ccc;
    -khtml-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #ccc;
}
```

It is working fine with browsers other than IE, but I want the same effect in IE. If anybody is willing to help, it will be appreciated.

You can check the effect at http://jsfiddle.net/shabirgilkar/Mu9jL/.

Comment: The usual golden solution ([CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/)) doesn't work with `inset`. Just thought I'd point that out.

Comment: @thirtydot - bit of a shame that. I doubt there will be any other working solution for this, short of using images. oh well. :-/

Answer (score 6):

IE 8 and below don't support the `box-shadow` CSS3 property, but it might be possible to get it to work. You should check these articles out...

- http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/cross-browser-box-shadows/
- http://dimox.net/cross-browser-css3-box-shadow/
- http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/

I would recommend using images for IE 8 and below (use conditional stylesheets).

I came up with a crappy solution, but it works in IE 8, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera. Check out the fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/Mu9jL/3/

I hope this helps.
Hristo

Answer (score 0):

http://css3generator.com/

Select box shadow

```
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px #313199;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px #313199;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px #313199;
```

What version of IE are you referring to? The different versions are vastly different.

Comment: he ask about inner shadow not outer shadow

Comment: you can just choose inset in the interface

Comment: I am asking about Inner shadow of the div in IE (below IE8) as i had shown in http://jsfiddle.net/shabirgilkar/Mu9jL/

Comment: @Homer6 I m targeting IE8 and below

Comment: Use sliding doors then. The css is not supported below 9. http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/

Comment: @Homer6 my div has not got static size it is dynamic... so i think Sliding doors may cause a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

At current (November 2011) it does not appear that anyone has developed a polyfill for IE8 or IE7 to do what you want.  See, for instance, CSS3PIE (https://github.com/lojjic/PIE/issues/3) which has box-shadow support but does not support the inset flag.

Your best (only?) option is to create an image to use as the background for the element.  This is, obviously, not a great solution.

(Also, to help you and others find other useful polyfills, here's a possibly useful link: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills)