# inset box shadow IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QsWYA/) that displays an inset box shadow.

I'd like to achieve this type of affect in I.E. Is there a jquery box shadow I can apply, a work around to IE's troubles?

I've looked at htcPIE but it didn't behave nicely with my current application. Any other hints?

The code that works in modern browsers is:

```
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 4px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 4px #000;
  box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 4px #000;
```

I was looking at in IE like :

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
```

but I'm missing the inset on the IE version.

Anyone have any luck with this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800491/inner-shadow-to-div-in-ie

Comment: Don't we all just love Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only useful hint is the following:

If it's not absolutely necessary, omit this effect for IE8. There is no equivalent MS-Filter for that and if css3PIE didn't work out for you, you are pretty much lost if you don't want to use images.

However a last solution would be to let the user install [chrome-frame](https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/) which I would consider not acceptable for such "gimmicks".

When developing your sites, never rely on those features like inner box-shadow if you don't want to lose IE community. Use it for decoration but don't do anything that would severly affect the Usability if not present.

Comment: In that case let the user download Chrome or Firefox themselves =P But overall, I agree with this, just omit it for IE8.

Comment: Oh, I know it's not possible to have the user download another browser, but in an ideal world... =P (I was just kidding with that part of it anyway) But I agree - use CSS3 for decoration purposes, not functionality - especially if IE is a main source of your traffic.

Comment: @Andy In the ideal webdeveloper world, there would be only one browser supporting all the webstandards to 100% without any bugs =D

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution that works for IE without css3PIE .  In IE 7/8 the element to which the shadow is applied, needs to have a background color set. Otherwise the shadow is inherited by child elements (including text).

here is how I achieve box shadow across all browsers...of course you'll need to customize for your own colors, strength, direction etc.

```
.shadow {
     -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #A7A7A7;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #A7A7A7;
     box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #A7A7A7;
     -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=3, Direction=135, Color='#A7A7A7')";
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=3, Direction=135, Color='#A7A7A7');
}

.wrapper{
    margin: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #A7A7A7;
    background-color: white;//or whatever color you need; however transparent doesn't work
   }
```

Then just apply both classes

```
<div class="wrapper shadow">
     <div>
          <p>Some text that used to have a shadow, but doesn't anymore</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh no, Anders you are correct! Let me help you with a CSS-only answer for Internet Explorer 5.5 through 8.